# jvm tuning with apache ignite

Tags: java, scala, jvm, ignite

[Ignite TCP SPI discovery, and memory management in ignite embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47381037/ignite-tcp-spi-discovery-and-memory-management-in-ignite-embedded)

Linking to my original question. I was able to run my program with 3GB over head memory, and with the recommended settings for jvm given in the original documentation for g1gc. Would like to highlight again, that my dataset size was 300mb in partitioned cache mode, and which had 24 million tuples approximately.

-Xms7g

-Xmx7g

-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch

-XX:+UseG1GC

-XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC

-XX:+DisableExplicitGC

However, the program is quite unstable. It works and sometimes it doesnt with the same settings. Plus, I ran a self join as described in the linked question, and it ran very slow. What am I missing here? I mean
1) I expected such queries to run instantaneously.
2) I would also like to tune the jvm better, but have tried a bunch of setting apart from the ones listed above, but couldn't find anything which works.

Comment: When you say that you program sometimes doesn't work, how exactly it manifests? Is there any error or exception?

Comment: If you think that GC is cause of your problem than you need to enable GC logs and analyze them. Without it difficult to suggest something useful.